# Accessing OAuth2 protected Resource with Spring WebClient where the token provider is also ssl protected

Tags: spring, ssl, oauth-2.0, webclient

trying to use webclient to access an OAuth2 protected token and resource server. The requirement is to add certificates to both requests. Here is more or less how I try to add certs to my request:

```html
 HttpClient resourceServerHttpClient = HttpClient.create()
        .tcpConfiguration(client -> client.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000))
        .secure(sslContextSpec -> {
          sslContextSpec.sslContext(oAuth2ClientSSLPropertiesConfigurer.getConstructedSslContexts().get("cpd"));
        });
    ClientHttpConnector customHttpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(resourceServerHttpClient);

    return WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(lisClientBaseUrl)
        .exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies)
        .clientConnector(customHttpConnector)
        .filter(oauth)
        .filters(exchangeFilterFunctions -> {
          exchangeFilterFunctions.add(logRequest());
          exchangeFilterFunctions.add(logResponse());
        })
        .build();
```

Question 1 : The snippet above passes certificates to the resource server request only, as far as I can understand. Found https://neuw.medium.com/spring-boot-oauth2-mutual-tls-client-client-credentials-grant-3cdb7a2a44ea where my customization fits Scenario-3. But then the only way is to switch fully reactive context (not servlet) in my api, to access DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager, authorizedClientProvider etc.  Is there a simpler way to achieve this?
Question 2 : Is there a way to see more details regarding the request to the token provider - to make sure that certificates are sent.

Comment: Are you using spring boot web?

Comment: Like not webflux?

Comment: PS - Am author of that link :-)

Comment: Hi! thanks for the great article the only resource for my case :) and the respose !

Comment: Spring boot web - running with a servlet context - not webflux